# Big data architecture: Elasticsearch-Kibana with Hive or Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, apache-spark, hdfs, kibana

I am dealing with a problem: I want to make a datavizualisation & prediction infrastructure.

I thought about Kibana+Elasticsearch on Hdfs (with ES-Hadoop), & Spark (Python) on Hdfs for modelisation.

My question is: can I properly index data in Hdfs with ES, or should I use Hive or Spark between Elasticsearch & Hdfs ?

I don't know which architecture is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

[ES-Hadoop](https://www.elastic.co/products/hadoop) will allow you to index data in HDFS directly with Elasticsearch. If you need to manipulate the data on its way from HDFS to ES, for example, performing lookups or filtering out data based on some criteria, you could use a tool like [StreamSets Data Collector](https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector/blob/master/README.md) - see [the blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-plus-streamsets-reliable-data-ingestion) for a bit more detail.

Full disclosure - I'm the community champion at StreamSets.

Comment: I don't know if my question was explicit... I mean, is it good to index directly data on HDFS or is it preferable to index data with Hive ?

Answer (score 0):

if your question is regarding the performance difference with indexing in hive and hadoop .... There will not be any difference . Even in the case of hive data is stored in HDFS and can be accessed thorough external tables in hive.... the way you want to use the indexes will determine your choice.... Hive will provide a structure on the data and you can apply many inbuilt functions to operate on data...

Comment: Does Hive duplicated the data stored in HDFS or juste provide a structure on HDFS ? I mean is the data both in the filesystem and Hive ?

Comment: If its an external table ... the data just resides in hdfs not duplicated in hive warehouse ...